# How to clean up dynamically created class instances?

Tags: angular, typescript

just to preface-- I am new to angular so I apologize if this is not a good way to handle this problem!

So I have a scenario where there are x amount of rooms-- and for simplicity lets say that whenever someone goes in, I am able to get the time that happens.

So now I would like to see the elapsed time that someone has been in a room.

Here is the demo on [Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pl3uet?file=src/app/app.component.css).

I hardcoded the room instances but eventually I would fetch the values dynamically from a backend.

So the question I am trying to get to is if the way I am going about doing this process (specifically the elapsed time) the correct way? I set an interval in the RoomWidget Class and I manually set clear the interval with NgOnDestroy, but is that enough? I was thinking that even after doing that, the class instances are still alive and thus leaky. I just couldn't figure out a better way about solving this problem and felt as though I over complicated all of this.

I genuinely do appreciate any comments or constructive criticism I should be aware of for this stuff-- thank you!

Comment: Looks fine to me - you are unsubscribing the only subscription when the encapsulating object is destroyed _edit: the only subscribed subscription - you don't need to declare `timer$ = new Subscription()` since you are replacing it in the constructor_ - but have you tried testing to see if it creates a memory leak?

Comment: I figured that you would need a subscription for an interval but I forgot that you could just clear the interval-- but look at the guys code below, that is literally dream code haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother managing the subscription myself. You can refactor your `room-widget.model` to below and let the consumer manage when it wants to subscribe, etc. (in this case, angular itself manages the subscription):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7r6ocu?file=src/app/room-widget.model.ts

```
import { timer, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class RoomWidget {
  readonly elapsedTime$ = !this.sessionStartTime
    ? EMPTY
    : timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        map(_ => {
          const totalSeconds = Math.floor(
            (new Date().getTime() - this.sessionStartTime!.getTime()) / 1000
          );

          const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
          const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
          const seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

          return { hours, minutes, seconds };
        })
      );

  constructor(
    public readonly id: string,
    public readonly status: string,
    private readonly sessionStartTime?: Date
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: I really like this implementation holy. So to make sure I can understand this (because I did not know about half of these rxjs functions), it does a null check with `!this.sessionStartTime ? EMPTY : ...`, if it has a value it will do the elapsed time. However, what is the `startWith(0)` used for? I tried searching stuff up about it but I believe it may be deprecated soon. I can't figure out what it's used for though. Thank you so much for the response though, seriously!

Comment: @josh `startWith` is used because `interval` emitts the first event 1 sec after the subcription is made. If you comment it out and use a bigger interval, you'll see it takes a while for the first render. I guess you could also do `concat(of(0), interval(1000))` instead of `startWith` or `timer(0, 1000)`, etc...